# TeXworks: Compile only current document with \includeonly

Tags: include, texworks

I have a large document with multiple parts:

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\include{part1}
\end{document}
```

`part1.tex`:

```
% !TEX root = main.tex
Hello World!
```

This way, I can compile the PDF with `part1.tex` open, and I can compile just one part (`\includeonly{part1}`).

Is there a way to compile only the current document, i.e., insert `\includeonly{currently opened file}` before compiling?

My first idea was to use LuaTeX to insert an `includeonly` depending on command line arguments (using the Lua variable `arg`), but then I still didn't find a way to append the command line parameter.

Comment: That's not possible. How would LaTeX know which document is "currently open" in your editor?

Comment: @Jubobs LaTeX doesn't know, but TeXworks knows.

Comment: @tstenner exactly so this probably needs to be an editor script rather than something (lua)tex does. I don't know texworks but certainly an editor such as emacs can easily edit the master file to add the name of the current buffer.

Comment: @tstenner Assuming countable `part1.tex`-`part10.tex`. you can add `\includeonly{currentpart}` manually to `main.tex` with `main.tex` and `currentpart.tex` windows open simultaneously in [TeXworks](https://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Defining_a_root_file). Post a [TeXworks feature request](https://code.google.com/p/texworks/issues/list).

Answer (score 1):

It isn't exactly what I was asking for, but I does the job quite well for me.
It uses Lua to determine the file that was changed last (so usually the file I am currently editing) and writes `\includeonly{file}` to the preamble.

`includeonlylastmodified.lua`

```
require "lfs"

function mtimesort(a,b)
   return lfs.attributes(a..'.tex',"modification")
```

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
   files = {'part1','part2'}
   dofile('includeonlylastmodified.lua')
}

\begin{document}
\include{part1}
\include{part2}
\end{document}
```